# Sonarqube dashboard to display SVN activities

Tags: sonarqube, dashboard

I am using Sonaqube 5.1 and the data is pushed from Teamcity CI server using SonarQube Runner. Since the SCM Activity plugin is no longer available, how do I get similar data in project dashboard? Something similar to the following http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index?did=79 is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question mentions two different things: SCM stats, and an existing dashboard on Nemo.

#### Dashboard

What you're looking at on that dashboard is two instances of the Measure Filter as List widget.

The widget on the left shows a shared filter called [Most Active Projects on Past 30 Days](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/measures/filter/58). Its criterion is the Lines of code metric, with the second differential period chosen (over 30 days) instead of "Value", and a threshold of > 200.

The widget on the right shows the [Most Active Developers on Past 30 Days](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/measures/filter/59). It has a similar criterion, this time on developers rather than projects.

You can construct a similar projects filter out of the box. To make a developers filter, you'll need to add the commercial [Developer Cockpit](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/) plugin.

#### SCM Stats

For SCM stats, there's no direct way to get this data anymore. Commit count used to be available as a project-level metric, but was dropped long ago as being less than helpful. I don't think it was ever collected on a developer-by-developer basis.

However, I'm wondering what it is you're really after. If you're looking for developer productivity (raw numbers are a **truly terrible** way to track that, BTW) then I would argue that commit count (which is unavailable anyway) is inaccurate: John made 200 commits of one line each, while Susan made four commits, each of 50 lines. Count by commits and John has done more "work", but count by new lines, which you can easily get from a combination of the SonarQube Platform and Developer Cockpit, and they've made an equal contribution.

Comment: Most probably I misunderstood the "Most Active Developers on Past 30 Days". What I am looking for is to find out from SVN commits, who are frequently committing codes into the project i.e. 10 most active committers/authors who are committing into svn and display a list into the dashboard - is that something filters can do?

Comment: @Shubhankar I've expanded my answer to address this

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed response. Completely agree that this cannot be a measure of  productivity. Rather, say in a large team a few members never committed a code - that's a red flag. We can of course drill down into the commit detail to see what exactly got changed. Something similar is given in TeamCity ChangeLog and were hoping to get this in this dashboard.

Comment: If you feel I've fully answered your question @Shubhankar, you might want to accept my answer. :)

Comment: I just appreciate your doing it @Shubhankar! :)